# Woocommerce Product Attribute Permalink doesn't work?

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

Normally, I can filter product by attribute via calling **"mysite.com/shop/?filter_brand=tesla"**

However, when I tried to call it as "mysite.com/brand/tesla" but it doesn't work and show 404 not found.

I keep this setting by default.
[image: Permalink Setting]

How can I call filter it as permalink i.e. **"mysite.com/brand/tesla"** ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Go to Attributes > Brand, edit the attribute, then enable the archive (there is an option), and finally re-save permalinks.

If it 404s from then, ensure there is no page or other taxonomy called 'brand' because it will conflict. Test another attribute if unsure.

Thanks

[Product attribute permalink doesn't work #16825](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/16825)

Comment: Thank you. Excellent

Comment: I had forgotten this tip - cheers!